# How do I access a MovieClip on the stage from the Document Class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a "box_mc" movieclip on the root of my stage and I need to select it from within my Document Class. I thought Stage.getChildByName("box_mc") would work, but it just returns null. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your document class, in the constructor add

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);
```

then in the function init:

```
private function init(e:Event):void
{

    getChildByName("box_mc") 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you're automatically declaring stage references (on by default, so unless you turned this off you're fine) then all you have to do is type box_mc.

In your document class constructor just type trace(box_mc) and it should work.